# JavaScript will not work with enter on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, magento-1.9

When I press search button my JS code will work.
But when I use enter to submit form Bellow code will not work.
Use of code in magento.
**Html**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('storelocator/index/searchbydistance') ?>" method="GET" id="search_by_distance">
<button type="button" onclick="storeSearch.submit(this)"><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></button></form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
storeSearch.submit = function(button, url) { 
alert('hi');
}.bind(storeSearch);
//]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the enter keypress form submission behaviour to work you need to have `submit` button within the `<form>` element. As all your current button does is submit the form through JS, you could simply change its `type`:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('storelocator/index/searchbydistance') ?>" method="GET" id="search_by_distance">
  <button type="submit"><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  storeSearch.submit = function(button, url) { 
    alert('hi');
  }.bind(storeSearch);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

give some id to to button and then use code like following:

```
    document.getElementById("id_of_button")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("id_of_button").click();
```

//OR submit your form.

```
    }
});
```